# Why should I use static schema methods on mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

Is there any difference of using this:

```
myModelSchema.static("doSomething", (id) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        MyModel.findById(id, (err, myModelDoc) => {
            if (err) { reject(err); }

            resolve(myModelDoc);
        });
    });
});

const MyModel = mongoose.model("MyModel", myModelSchema);
```

and this:

```
const MyModel = mongoose.model("MyModel", myModelSchema);

public static doSomething(id) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        MyModel.findById(id, (err, myModelDoc) => {
            if (err) { reject(err); }

            resolve(myModelDoc);
        });
    });
}
```

Should I attach the static methods to the schema or is it ok to do it outside?

Thanks

Comment: I thing it's just convenient to have the method attached to your model. It makes it easy to use `MyModel.doSomething(...)`

Comment: Well, if it's just for convenience, I guess I prefer to declare the methods outside, this way my typescript can recognize them and facilitates the coding. Just thought I could lose performance or something doing it outside :). Thanks for the comment.